# Filter off lines using Regex

Tags: python, regex

My big tab-delimited file with some text before and after,EDITED

```
chr3Av1G678.1 chr2Bv1G678.9
chr1Av1G978.6 chr1Bv1G456.1
chr2Av1G123.4 chr2Bv1G678.3
chr1Av1G456.0 chr2Av1G784.22
```

How to filter off from file 1A-1B and 2A-2B?So that I have only 3A 2B and 1A 2A

```
import re
import sys
f=open('input.txt','r') 
r=open('output.txt','w')
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.split()
    if not (?) re.search(r'text1Av1', line[0]) and not (?) re.search(r'text1Bv1', line[1]):
        r.write("\t".join(line)+"\n")
f.close()
r.close()
```

Comment: why are you "filtering off" `1A 1B` and `2A 2B`? Is it because the number at the start of each letter is the same?

Comment: Your filtering condition is not really clear. Under what conditions do you want lines filtered?

Comment: What do you want to keep and what do you want to leave? What are the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution if you want keep your text and only filter out the two lines.

**UPDATE** Regex!

```
import re
import sys
with open('input.txt','r') as f, open('output.txt','w') as r:
    for line in f:
        if None is re.search(r'^chr[12]Av1G\d+\.\d+\s*chr[12]Bv1G\d+\.\d+$',line):
            r.write(line)
```

Comment: can you explain your '[12]A\s*[12]B', so I can modify, becuase as I said above my lines do not contain only 1A-1B but textA1v1number text1Bv1number

Comment: [12] means '1' and '2' are valid chars,
A means 'A',
\s* means any number of whitespaces,
[12] like first line,
and B means 'B'

a good tool to validate your regex yourself: http://pythex.org/

Comment: Maybe you can post a 'full' example of your input and output to help you find a good regex that fits your data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep lines where you have a number then A or B, then immediately following (e.g. after a tab) a different number followed by A or B, the following should work:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_lines = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
    for line in read_lines:
        get_digits = re.match(r'.*(\d)+[AB]\s+(\d)+[AB].*', line, re.DOTALL)
        if get_digits:
            if get_digits.group(1) != get_digits.group(2):
                o.writelines(line)
```

This will write to `output.txt` the lines which contain `3A  2B` and `1A  2A`.

To generalise this further, you could change the regex to:

```
re.match(r'.*(\d)+[A-Z]\s+(\d)+[A-Z].*', line, re.DOTALL)
```

Which would allow for any capital letters, not just A and B.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
import re

with open('input', 'r') as f, open('output', 'w') as f2:
    ftemp = f.read()
    for a in range(1,4):
        res = '-'.join(sorted(set(re.findall(r'{}[A-Z]'.format(a), ftemp))))
        print res
        f2.write(res)
```

Output of `print res`:

```
1A-1B
2A-2B
3A
```

Step:

Create a range() object with the numbers you want to capture from the file. Then search for those numbers + 1 caps alphabet in the file.